# Object assign same key different value

Tags: javascript, object, oop

```js
function storage(data) {

  let object = {};

  data.forEach(line => {
    let [product, quantity] = line.split(' ');
    if (!object[product]) {
      object[product] = quantity;
    } else {
      let currentQuantity = Object.assign(object[product] = quantity); < -- - problem comes from here
      let newQuantity = Number(currentQuantity) + Number(quantity);
      Object.assign(product, newQuantity);
    }
  });

}
storage(['tomatoes 10', 'coffee 5', 'olives 100', 'coffee 40']);
```

Hello , I am new in the OOP and I want to combine different values from a key with same name.

output wanted `['tomatoes 10', 'coffee 45', 'olives 100']`

Comment: The function needs to return `object`.

Comment: `Object.assign(product, newQuantity)` should be `object[product] = newQuantity`

Comment: @Barmar on currentQuantity = Object.assign(object[product] = quantity); // It gets the new value of coffee witch is 40 , and i want to get the current value of coffee (5) that is in the object  and combine the current value of coffee (5) with the new one (40) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `Object.assign()`. That's for merging objects, not assigning a specific property. Just retrieve and assign  `object[product]`.

At the end you need to convert `object` back to an array of strings and return that.

```js
function storage(data) {

  let object = {};

  data.forEach(line => {
    let [product, quantity] = line.split(' ');
    quantity = Number(quantity);
    if (!object[product]) {
      object[product] = quantity;
    } else {
      object[product] += quantity;
    }
  });
  return Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => `${key} ${value}`);
}

console.log(storage(['tomatoes 10', 'coffee 5', 'olives 100', 'coffee 40']));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this a lot.  There's no real benefit to be gained from using `Object.assign`.  You probably also want to explicitly convert your quantities to numbers instead of using strings.

```js
let displayStock = (data) => Object.entries(data).map( ([k, v]) => `${k} ${v}` )

function storage(data) {

  let object = {};

  data.forEach(line => {
    let [product, quantity] = line.split(' ');
    object[product] = (object[product] || 0) + Number(quantity)
  });
  return object;
}
let stock = storage(['tomatoes 10', 'coffee 5', 'olives 100', 'coffee 40']);

console.log(displayStock(stock))
```